# Passing a JSON object from clientside JavaScript to NodeJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a webpage which creates a JSON object based on user input. I would like to then somehow allow the user to submit this JSON object to a NodeJS script for processing/insertion into a MySQL database. However, I'm really not sure how to do something like this -- the best I can come up with is some form of a POST, but I'm not sure where to start with this.

Because I don't know what such a method would be described as, I haven't had much success in locating any tutorials or other resources online.

Could anyone suggest some articles or documentation to look at that would be relevant to something like this? Or, at least, tell me what to search for? Thanks.

EDIT: This is the code I am trying to get working at the moment. I'm just trying to convert the POST data type from string to JSON on both sides.

Serverside:

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('GET /')
    //var html = '<html><body><form method="post" action="http://localhost:3000">Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></form></body>';
    var html = fs.readFileSync('index.html');
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(html);
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('POST /');
    console.dir(req.body);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end('thanks');
});

port = 8080;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening at http://localhost:' + port)
```

Clientside:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        console.log('begin');
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var params = "text=stuff";
        http.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080", true);

        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        //http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            console.log('onreadystatechange');
            if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                alert(http.responseText);
            }
            else {
                console.log('readyState=' + http.readyState + ', status: ' + http.status);
            }
        }

        console.log('sending...')
        http.send(params);
        console.log('end');

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A post is correct, if you want to do this without refreshing the page, you'll need AJAX. You'll also need a route to catch this on your server (in Express, something like `app.post("/api/test")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very basic example using jQuery to do the post request and an express app. I think it should be a decent starting point.

```
// client side, passing data to the server
$.post("/foo/", { data : { foo : "bar" } }, function(temp) {
    // temp === "I am done";    
});

// serverside app.js

var express = require("express");

var app = express();

// will parse incoming JSON data and convert it into an object literal for you
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());

app.post("/foo/", function(req, res) {
    // each key in req.body will match the keys in the data object that you passed in
    var myObject = req.body.data;
    // myObject.foo === "bar"
    res.send("I am done");
});
```

**EDIT:** JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() will serialize/deserialize JSON. (jQuery makes this much easier, but if you wanna go pure javascript)

Change to `var params = "text=" + JSON.stringify({ foo : "bar" });`

and

`console.dir(JSON.parse(req.body.text));`

It worked for me on my local.

Comment: Thanks for your sample code. Unfortunately, I'm still quite new to Express (and Node.js in general) so I was unable to get it running. Could you point me in the right direction with this? For the moment, I've simply created a button which should trigger the post action like so: $.post("localhost:8080/hello", { data : { foo : "bar" } }, function(temp) {
    alert(temp);

Comment: Which part isn't working and can you edit your question with the code for your express App.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure -- I've added the code above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've managed to get a string POST working... however the problem now is changing it to JSON. Any ideas?